# Primal updates for augmented Lagrangian in ADMM

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, proximal-operators

I am reading this tutorial that uses ADMM:

https://waller-lab.github.io/DiffuserCam/tutorial/algorithm_guide.pdf

The objective function that needs to be minimized and the augmented Lagrangian is written as
[image]

The primal update for the variable **v** in the document is then given as:

[image]

I had expected the primal update to have the fourth, sixth, and the eighth terms of the objective function expression i.e. Eq. 4 as well, as they have the variable **v**, but clearly I am missing something. Why are these terms not included in the primal update expression?

Comment: Well, if you want you can include. However, finding a solution to the subproblem may be difficult.

Comment: In the referred document, it seems there are four subproblems for the primal variables update (like in a multiblock ADMM).